# Product Borel algebra for subsets

Tags: real-analysis, abstract-algebra, analysis, measure-theory

Let X and Y be topological spaces. For all subsets $Z$ of $Y$ follows

$$\mathcal{B}(X \times Y) = \mathcal{B}(X) \otimes \mathcal{B}(Y) \Longrightarrow \mathcal{B}(X \times Z) = \mathcal{B}(X) \otimes \mathcal{B}(Z)$$

I was trying to use the second axiom of countability for $Z$ (since $Y$ satisfies it) . Then I could just copy paste the proof of the first equality but I am not sure if this is the right way.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When $X$ and $Y$ are topological spaces, we have that

$$ \mathcal B (X) \otimes \mathcal B (Y) \subset \mathcal B(X \times Y). $$

However, as you suggest, if $X$ and $Y$ are both second-countable, we have that

$$ \mathcal B (X) \otimes \mathcal B (Y) = \mathcal B(X \times Y). $$

Any $Z \subset Y$ is also second-countable whenever we endow $Z$ with the [subspace topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subspace_topology).

Hence, as long as $Z$ is also second-countable (whether through the subspace topology or otherwise), we also have that

$$ \mathcal B (X) \otimes \mathcal B (Z) = \mathcal B(X \times Z). $$

I'm not certain what you mean by "copying and pasting the proof", but the result stated above regarding second-countable spaces $X$ and $Y$ certainly applies to second-countable spaces $X$ and $Z$ as well, regardless of whether $Z\subset Y$ or not.